# mvn package can't find dependency jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I know there are many threads on this, but my question is very simple.

1. I have the abc.jar (which is my own jar, not any open source jar) in my build path in Eclipse.  The project compiles fine.
2. I have the following pom.xml (snippet).
3. When I run "mvn package", it can not find my classes in abc.jar file.

Thanks for your help.

```xml
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: try installing abc.jar in your local maven repository and then add its entry in your maven dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: Have you added you own jar as dependency and why are you using such an old version of maven-assembly-plugin.

Comment: thanks for comments, but how do I add abc.jar in my local maven repository ? I tried from eclipse by copying the the jar file from "reference libraries" section to "maven repository" but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use maven install command to install your jar in maven repository like this

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<jar-file-path> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then you can use it in your pom.xml like regular maven dependency with groupid, artifact id and version